# stop player sliding when moving

Tags: javascript, html, phaser-framework

I'm making a game in Phaser. When my player moves left or right it keeps on moving a little while before it stops. Is there a way I can stop this to get more responsive movement?

The code is like this:

```
if(cursors.left.isDown){
    player.body.velocity.x += -20;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stop the `player` immediately you can simply set the `player.body.velocity.x` to 0.

```
player.body.velocity.x = 0;
```

A number of the official tutorials, such as this [Mass Velocity Test](http://phaser.io/examples/v2/arcade-physics/mass-velocity-test) show an example of this. In that case they actually reset both the x and y velocity to 0 at the beginning of the `update()` call. This allows for immediate stopping and starting.

If for some reason you wanted acceleration but immediate stopping, you could probably just use an else.

```
if (cursors.left.isDown) {
    player.body.velocity.x += -20;
} else {
    player.body.velocity.x = 0;
}
```

You could also store the velocities in a variable and then use that in your if statement instead. Untested:

```
currentVelocity = player.body.velocity.x;
player.body.velocity.x = 0;

if (cursors.left.isDown) {
    player.body.velocity.x = currentVelocity - 20;
}
```